# SQLAlchemy and foreign keys doesn't work when deleting rows

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have API - python script (using Flask and SQLite) which works with database with 3 tables.

Table Comany has relationship 1:N with table User. And table Company has relationshipt 1:N with table Keyword.

Now, if I will delete some company, I expect it will also delete all users who belong to company, as well as all keywords.

I have found, I have to turn on FOREIGN Keys, using these lines

```
@event.listens_for(Engine, "connect")
def set_sqlite_pragma(dbapi_connection, connection_record):
    if type(dbapi_connection) is sqlite3.Connection:  # play well with other DB backends
       cursor = dbapi_connection.cursor()
       cursor.execute("PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON")
       cursor.close()
```

However it will still only delete company, and foregin keys in rows of users as well as keywords of this company stay NULL.

E.g. Table User
[ID, Name, Pass, FK_company_name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l5Ybf.png)

These are lines how I am deleting company

```
...
company_id = request.args.get('company_id')
company = Company.query.get(company_id)
db.session.delete(company)
db.session.commit()
...
```

Do I have to set something else?

Comment: You need a delete cascade at either the SQLAlchemy level or the database level.  Can you share your models' code?

Comment: you have to add cascade attr in your relationship likes `cascade="all,delete-orphan",`